# How to query connected device IP addresses on LAN

Tags: android

I'm writing an application that should scan a local area network for connected devices, and return the IP addresses of connected devices.

My scanner consists of "pinging" each IP within a range of IP addresses. This process of pining a range of IP addresses is time consuming.

Then I learned there is something called an ARP (address resolution protocol) cache on Windows machines which is basically a list of valid IP addresses, or IP addresses of connected devices.

So since Android isn't Windows, is there a way to access a similar table simply using an API or something?

Tl;Dr How can I query valid IP addresses on a network (not ping them) in Android

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I came up with so far was to read the ARP file in the Android device at file path `/proc/net/arp`

Here's the main activity class for the app that displays the file content in a simple text view

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        // Get an array list of mac to IP address mapping
        ArrayList<String> arpTableLines = getArpTableLines();

        // Generate a string to display in the text view based on the mapping
        String textViewText = getTextViewText(arpTableLines);

        // Set the text view value
        tv.setText(textViewText);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getArpTableLines(){

        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

        try{

            String line = "";

            BufferedReader localBufferdReader =
                    new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/proc/net/arp")));

            while ((line = localBufferdReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] ipmac = line.split("[ ]+");
                if (!ipmac[0].matches("IP")) {
                    String ip = ipmac[0];
                    String mac = ipmac[3];
                    lines.add(ip + " <~> " + mac);
                }
            }

        }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
            Log.v("TAG",Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
        } catch (IOException ex){
            Log.v("TAG",Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
        }

        return lines;
    }

    public String getTextViewText(ArrayList<String> lines){
        String result = "";
        for(String line : lines) result += line + "\n";
        return result;
    }
}
```